# What does "nvm use" command do in Windows?

Tags: node.js, nvm

Does it edit windows registries?
Adds something to PATH?
Adds environment variables to user profile?
Stores something to APP_DATA directory?

What exactly is the outcome of "nvm use" command? And how given setting is persisted into the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> NVM for Windows maintains a single symlink that is put in the system `PATH` during installation only. Switching to different versions of node is a matter of switching the symlink target. As a result, this utility does not require you to run `nvm use x.x.x` every time you open a console window. When you do run `nvm use x.x.x`, the active version of node is automatically updated across all open console windows. It also persists between system reboots, so you only need to use nvm when you want to make a change.

[source](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows#whats-the-big-difference)

Symlink is located under `%NVM_SYMLINK%` wich defaults to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and versions are downloaded under `%NVM_HOME%` which defaults to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\nvm`

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, Actually I tried to run `nvm use 10.7.0`. And immediately command returned following output in the console: `Now using node v10.7.0 (64-bit)`.
But `node -v` still says `command not found`. That's the reason I asked this question.
Do you know where can I look for these symlinks?

Comment: I'm using a custom NVM_HOME. `nvm install 10.7.0` installed node in this directory: `%NVM_HOME%/v10.7.0` not under `Program Files`. Probably that's the issue.
The only solution I see now is to put manually this to my PATH: `%NVM_HOME%\v10.7.0` which is very inconvenient manual approach. Looks like there is no point of using nvm at all if you define your custom NVM_HOME.
Thanks @GabrielBlue for sharing your answers. At least now I know what the command does.

Comment: Yes that's the point, node versions are downloaded under `%NVM_HOME%` and then `%NVM_SYMLINK%` should be updated to target the new version.